# How to use Linux to read a file line by line and replace all the spaces into ','?

Tags: linux, shell, file-io

I am a beginner.. I'd like to use Linux shell to make the following file

```
1 2 2
2 3 4
4 5 2
4 2 1
....
```

into

```
1,2,2
2,3,4
4,5,2
4,2,1
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please post what you've tried, we're not here to do your homework (or business work) for you. You can do it easily with `awk` or `bash` variable substitution operators.

Comment: Or even easier with `sed`.

Comment: First you post about `awk` or `bash`, I think okay I'll add `sed`. Then you go sed, ok I'll add `tr`. Now this.

Comment: how about using cut instead? :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this:-

```
sed -e "s/ /,/g" < a.txt
```

or may be easier like this:

```
tr ' ' ',' <input >output
```

or in Vim you can use the Regex:

```
s/ /,/g
```

Answer (score 1):

The question asks "line by line".  In `bash` :

```
while read line; do echo $line | sed 's/ /,/g'; done < file
```

It will read `file` line by line into `line`, print (`echo`) each line and pipe (`|`) it to `sed` which will change spaces into commas.  You can add `> newfile` at the end (but `> file` won't work) if you need to store it in a file.

But if you don't need anything else than changing characters in the file, processing the whole file at once is easier and probably quicker :

```
sed -i 's/ /,/g' file
```

(option `-i` is for modifying the file directly, as opposed to print modifications to `stdout`).

Read more about `sed` to understand its syntax, you'll need it eventually.